# Image inside a cell overlapping other cells in MigraDoc

Tags: c#, pdf, migradoc

I want to put an image inside a tables cell in MigraDoc, but I end up with image stretching the whole row. The part of the simpilfied code looks like so:

```
table = sec.AddTable();
table.Borders.Width = 0.1; //only for visualization

column = table.AddColumn("6cm");
column = table.AddColumn("7.5cm");
column = table.AddColumn("2.5cm");

row = table.AddRow();
row[0].AddParagraph("title");
row[1].AddImage("C:\\sample.jpg").Width = "3cm";
row = table.AddRow();
row[0].AddParagraph("   - some text");
row = table.AddRow();
row[0].AddParagraph("   - some text");
row = table.AddRow();
row[0].AddParagraph("   - some text");
row = table.AddRow();
row[2].AddParagraph("0.00$");
```

First image below shows the result and the second one - the desired effect.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set `.WrapFormat.Style = WrapStyle.Through` for the image then the image will be ignored by the layouter and the height of the row will not be adapted to the image.

If the table has borders then you may have to add the image after the table to have it drawn on top of the table.

A simple alternative could be using `.MergeDown` for the table cell with the image. This is like RowSpan in HTML. In this case the table will grow to fit the image, so you cannot get the effect of the second image (image extends below the table).
This avoids the complications that come with WrapStyle.Through if you have to deal with many different image sizes and should give you clean pagebreaks if the table should not fit a single page.

The Invoice sample does not use images in tables, but it used `MergeDown`:
http://pdfsharp.net/wiki/Invoice-sample.ashx